# Legal Way to Define JavaScript Object in terms of Other Variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

My very simple question is that I want to know if the following code is legal:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = {a,b};
```

Backstory: I can use the above code in Chrome, but IE 11 does not seem to work with this. Is there a similar (i.e. concise) way to do this that will work in all (recent) browsers?

Comment: `var c = { a: a, b: b };` isn’t concise enough?

Comment: This seems to answer both of your questions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Syntax

Comment: minitech: No, I don't think that is concise enough. My variable names can be quite long. Felix: I am considering using an ES6 shim for IE so thanks for the useful info about the changes in ES6.

Comment: @picomp: Just use `var c = {a:1, b:2}`? How would you expect it to be even more concise, what syntax do you imagine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's valid ES2015. Next most concise thing for engines that don't support that is regular `{a: a, b: b}`.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer! I am still pretty new at this so I have a followup question. Is it a good idea to use an ES6 shim for IE to enable this behavior? [something like this](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim)

Comment: @picomp You're welcome! You can only shim objects / methods, not syntax, which this is. You can transpile syntax (e.g. with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)) -- you may want to look into that. There are pros and cons, which is too big of a topic to get into in the comments here, but you should be able to find information discussing that.

Comment: I did some more research about transpilation and shims and found [this useful website](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). The question I originally asked related to object literal extensions by the way.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean, but any "literal extensions" are syntax and can be transpiled, but not shimmed.

Answer (score 1):

That's ecmascript 6 style object declaration. I'm not sure if IE will ever implement modern standards, but at the time being now, use this instead:

```
var c = {a:a,b:b}
```

Comment: no, IE will never improve from 11, it's dead. long live edge.